# scrape href attribute value from inside spans with ID

Tags: php, web-scraping

OK folks the page Im trying to scrape has the following structure

```
<span id="1">
    <a href="https://example.com">+</a>
    <span title="1">DATA HERE</span>
    <a href="https://example.com">DATA HERE</a> 
    <a href="https://example.com">DATA HERE</a>
</span>
<span id="2">
    <a href="https://example.com">+</a>
    <span title="1">DATA HERE</span>
    <a href="https://example.com">DATA HERE</a> 
    <a href="https://example.com">DATA HERE</a>
</span>
```

There are 128 records on the page ( spans with ID values )

I am using the following code but its saving the data which is great but i need each a href attribute value seperated by a , until it gets to the last one inside the span with the ID and then I need to to have PHP_EOL to move to a new line

Please help I'm pulling hair out

Code :

```
do {
    foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('span') as $element ) { 

        if (!empty($element->getAttribute('id'))){

            foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('a') as $ahref ) {

                if ($ahref->hasAttribute('href')) { 
                    $filename = 'test2/'.$f.'.txt';
                    $file = fopen($filename,"a");

                    $data = $ahref->getAttribute('href').',';
                    fwrite($file,$data);
                    fclose($file);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what was the issue in your code?

Comment: its saving the data but I cant get it to only apply a , to the 1st and 2nd value a href values the 3rd a href attribute needs a PHP_EOL  before it moves onto the next span with an ID

Comment: so `break or exit` loop after `2 href get`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a piece of code using [`DomDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [`DomXPath`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) that I think will give you the results you want. It finds all the spans that have an `id` attribute, then iterates their children looking for `a` elements. When it finds one, it adds its `href` attribute to the list of `hrefs` for this span. Once all the children of the span have been processed, the list of `hrefs` is output, comma-separated on its own line.

```
$html = '<span id="1">
    <a href="https://example.com">+</a>
    <span title="1">DATA HERE</span>
    <a href="https://example.com">DATA HERE</a> 
    <a href="https://example.com">DATA HERE</a>
</span>
<span id="2">
    <a href="https://example.com">+</a>
    <span title="1">DATA HERE</span>
    <a href="https://example.com">DATA HERE</a> 
    <a href="https://example.com">DATA HERE</a>
</span>';
$doc = new DomDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DomXPath($doc);
$spans = $xpath->query("//span[@id]");
foreach ($spans as $span) {
    $hrefs = array();
    foreach ($span->childNodes as $n) {
        if ($n->nodeName == 'a') {
            $hrefs[] = $n->attributes->getNamedItem('href')->nodeValue;
        }
    }
    echo implode(',', $hrefs) . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
https://example.com,https://example.com,https://example.com 
https://example.com,https://example.com,https://example.com
```

Comment: Perfect many thanks
Is there a way to do a str_replace and remove the https://example.com from the url before it echos it as there is data after that which is what i need

Comment: Which is the actual data that you need?

Comment: its ok ive managed to add 2 str_replaces as there is different data after each url before the exact data I needed. Working perfectly now , many thanks :)

Comment: Cool. As long as you're happy! :)

Comment: ahh I can get it to write to file now as its an array, how can I convert it to a string ?
so I can use fwrite and store it instead of just echo'ing the data

Comment: Use the same `implode` that I am using. That converts the array to a comma separated string.

Comment: Sorry going to be a pain again .. If i want to write the first href ( hrefs[0] ) into a seperate file and then write all 3 into a different file how would I go about that ?
Ive tried putting the code just after the foreach ($span->childNodes as $n) { loop but its writing the 1st href about 3 - 4 times in the file before moving onto the next span ( the file with the full data in is perfectly fine though

Comment: You should be able to just write `hrefs[0]` into the separate file at the same time as you write the imploded text into the other file.